# Power demand calculation

Tags: arduino, power, batteries

The title says it all.

I'm currently working on an Arduino project. The project involves connecting 3 - 6 different shields non which is a "Motor Shield".

They are VR, brain wave reader, GSM, GPS, TFT screen, and a camera.

What is the right way to calculate the power needed to be supplied to the total project by batteries?

What I know is that I have to calculate the amound of current withdrawn from each module in their highest peaks. Accordingly, I will choose the capacity of the battery that can operate the the amount of time I want.

Is  this the way it is done? Or am I missing something?
Is there any other concerns I have to keep an eye on?

Regarding the voltage, It shouldn't matter right? The shields are made specifically for Arduino, so if I powered it in the recommended range of voltages (7-12) I should be fine right?

Comment: You don't want to supply the 7-12V, since it goes through a linear regulator. Supply 5V directly instead.

Comment: You probably want average current not peak for estimating battery life. Unless you know how to calculate that for each shield just measuring how long it takes to flatten a battery of a known capacity and adding a bit of margin is probably a decent way to go about it.

Comment: I was referring to the power jack itself. I will be powering (7-12)v to the power jack directly. 
The shields are mounted on the the arduino, they will take the power from the (5v) pin or directly before the regulator as specified from their data sheet.
At the end, I will have to supply it through the power jack.

Comment: @PeterJ
So is this the only thing I have to worry about?
Any other relevant when connecting a battery?

Regarding adding the margin, what is normally a good percentage I have to multiply with after calculating the average current? Is 1.3 good enough?

Comment: Also keep in mind the C-rating of the battery. Pulling more current than it can supply will hurt the voltage.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams
That's a very important point thanks.

Comment: @AdelBibi, Ignacio is right about checking the C-rating as well, although for most batteries that can deliver reasonable current I can think of 1C is OK so unless you're aiming for an hour or less of operating time it should be OK. But best to double-check.

Comment: @PeterJ The only problem is with the GSM module. The moment an SMS is sent/received the withdrawal current can go as high as 1.5Amps. This is also way less than 2.2 C battery.
But a very good point indeed, thanks alot!

Comment: @AdelBibi, that may be less of a problem than you think, the peaks on a GSM module are often only a ms or so. When you add a reservoir cap (which hopefully your board has) it can largely be ignored. I did a design a while back using the vendor's reference design, and that only used a 500mA switching regulator and from memory something like a 2200uF cap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Current

Yes the right way to calculate current required is to work it out for each module and add them up. However, if you are combining Arduino modules, a practical way is to assemble them, power from a relatively high power source and measure the current. The only danger here is that you'll overload the Arduino's 5V or 3.3V regulators. I'd check that the specific Arduino has overcurrent or short-circuit protection.

Rather than measuring for all 5 daughterboards at once, you may be able to devise test programs for using them one at a time. Make measurements, then check the power supply path is adequate before combining all of them.

### Voltage

The voltage regulators on a typical Arduino are not expected to supply much current. See Arduino and/or regulator data sheets. As Ignacio commented, it may be advisable to provide for an off-board regulated 5V supply.

Comment: It's definitely advisable. Shoving 7.4V into a 5V linear regulator means you waste about 1/3 of your battery.

Comment: As for current,
I'm using an arduino mega. I couldn't find any thing relating the (overcurrent) except for the usb connection.
Where they say the following:


"The Arduino Mega has a resettable polyfuse that protects your computer's USB ports from shorts and overcurrent. "

is this the same max overcurrent the power jack or (vin) can handle?


Let me get this staright, when you say to use an off-board regulated 5v supply, do you mean I use a (for exapmle) 7.4v power supply connect it to a (High current) regulator and the out put connected to (+5).

Sorry I'm new to this!

Comment: At the end this won't solve the problem of high pwoer dissepation, but will only make sure the mega is safe. Did I get that correctly?


One last thing, what if the are to operate higher than (+5v)?

Comment: @AdelBibi `what if the are to operate higher than (+5v)?` Please rephrase the question. If you mean what are the alternatives to generate 5v you can use a switching regulator like [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/121208203049?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1497.l2648) (uses a LM2596) that has a high efficiency.

Comment: Sorry I missed typing that.
I meant, what if the modules operate to a higher volrage that +5v.
When I connect the off-board regulator to the (+5v) pin, that will only provide me with a 5v source. 
What if one of the modules operate at 7v?
@alexan_e

Comment: @AdelBibi So you mean if you feed 5v to the 5V input of arduino (output of the onboard regulators) and there is a shield that expects to find a voltage source >7v in the Vin pin (input side of the 5v regulator)? I guess in that case you have to feed the board with that higher voltage or use an external supply to the shield directly (if possible).

Comment: @alexan_e
That's perfect.
Therefore; I will only connect the off-coard 5 v regulator connected to the (+5v) pin in arduino when I'm sure all the other modules opperate on 5v.

Otherwise; I will have to connect a power supply that is higher around 7-12v through the power jack.


Thanks alot!